# JNDI reference and lookup resource without web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, jndi, servlet-3.0

My application has an external dependency where resource class is defined - e.g `com.sample.SomeResource`.
The application server where my application runs on, provide environment resources which I can use in my application. One of them is an instance of `com.sample.SomeResource`. If my app has web descriptor - web.xml I can use `<resource-ref>` tag to reference it:

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>SomeResource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>com.sample.SomeResource</res-type>
    </resource-ref>
```

and then I can lookup for it.

```
 try {
      InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
      SomeResource someResource= (SomeResource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/SomeResource");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      ...
    }
```

However, I want to get rid of the web.xml. Is there a way to define it programmatically (dynamically)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use javax.annotation.Resource annotation on a field.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/SomeResource")
 private SomeResource someResource;
```

Comment: Yes but this is annotation config. And I am able to access it only in managed objects - Servlets, Filters, etc. I need a way to look up for it programmatically in any object I want.